# Is there an order-preserving bijection of reals with complexity classes?

Tags: order-theory, computational-complexity

We can easily prove there are $c:=\beth_1$ computational complexity classes for positive-valued functions of one positive-integer variable. To prove there are at least $c$ classes, we note each $e^{an},\,e^{bn}$ with $a>b>0$ are in different complexity classes. To prove there are at most $c$ classes, we note any function $f$'s class is determined by its $\aleph_0$ values on $\mathbb{N}$, giving an upper bound of $c^{\aleph_0}=c$.

But does there exist a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to functions, say $F(x)=n\mapsto f(n)$, such that $x<y\implies F(x)\in o(F(y))$, with the image of $F$ including representatives of all complexity classes?

Comment: Why not $F(x)(n)=\exp(nx)$? Perhaps add floor/ceiling if you need natural numbers.

Comment: @sdcvvc That leaves out many complexity classes, e.g. $e^{nx}\ln n$.

Comment: I know nothing of computational complexity, so I ask an ignorant question: are  complexity classes linearly ordered?

Comment: I'm afraid they aren't in general, e.g. $n^4$ vs $n^{3+(-1)^n}$.

Comment: What is a complexity class, formally? I can think of a few things it could mean ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Suppose there was such map $F$. Let $f(x) = \sup \{(F(y)(x-y))^2 : y \in [0, x]\}$. For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is not in the complexity class of $F(x)$ since $f$ grows at least as fast as $y \mapsto (F(x)(y))^2$.